# projeção errada no mapa

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql, postgis

Estou a tentar inserir pontos numa layer usando leaflet e guardo esses pontos numa base de dados Postgres(Postgis). Com o geoserver consigo visualizar a layer porem os pontos aparecem me todos mal e sei que isto tem haver com a projeção mas ja tentei mudar para outro tipo e não fica direito na mesma

1-Layer no Geoserver com Srid EPSG:4326
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2-Inserção na base de dados Postgres
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu inserir por exemplo um ponto perto de Inglaterra, vai me aparecer no Sul de Africa

Comment: Tentou com WGS84 Projetado (EPSG 3857)? O EPSG: 4326 é pra uso em geóide (tipo Google Earth). O EPSG 3857 seria para o Google Maps (que também é o mesmo sistema do Leaflet) - você pode fazer a projeção matematicamente caso só tenha os valores em 4326

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acredito que os valores de latitude e longitude estão trocados.

Tente algo desta forma:

```
$coord = $_POST['stringCoord']['longitude'].' '.$_POST['stringCoord']['latitude'];
```